# how to use API when there's no binary

Tags: api, jar

Normally when I use an API I download the binary containing the JAR which I then add to the classpath. I want to try Curve API but there's no binary (and hence no JARs in the download). I'm using Eclipse and I have read that you can just add the zip file, but I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the `README.txt` in the zip file with Curve API? Let me quote it:

```
In the src directory, there is a makejar.bat file.  This file will
compile the nested Java files and create a Jar file called Capi.jar.
Compilation requires Java 1.2 or higher.  After the Jar file is
created, add it to the classpath.  Note: CAPI comes with MESP (Math
Expression String Parser).
```

If you use Windows Vista or 7 or 8, navigate to the folder with `makejar.bat`, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click at an empty spot, and select "Open Command Window Here". It will launch console window with `cmd.exe`; you should be able to see a line like `X:\Full\Path\To\The\Folder>` in it.

If you use Windows XP or lower, then press Start button, select Run, and type `cmd.exe`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then enter `cd "X:\Full\Path\To\The\Folder"` (the path should be in quotes), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If that folder is on the other drive than your current one (shown at the beginning of the prompt), then also type in the letter of the drive where that folder is located, the symbol `:`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So much for opening the command window! Now type in `makejar.bat`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I predict that you will see an awful lot of `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` lines. If that's so, then please locate `javac.exe` on your computer somehow—I suggest using Windows Search. After you locate it, go to the folder where it is; click on the address bar of that folder and copy the path to the buffer. Then switch back to the command window, type `set PATH="`, right-click and chose "Paste", type in `";%PATH%"`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that, try `makejar.bat`<kbd>Enter</kbd>—now it should work. If it does, you may also run `makeapi.bat` which will generate HTML documentation.

Comment: No- I didn't read it. I double clicked on the file you mentioned. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Having read this, I still don't know how to create the JAR I need

Comment: I found out how to run the bat file- I had to set the PATH environment variable to the directory containing javac and then drag and drop the bat file into the command line window and press enter

Comment: However, I've just tried the above process again and it doesn't work anymore.